# Simple mod_rewrite RewriteRule for messy legacy url's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

Launching a new website for a new client. Their old site has about 50 products and unfortunately, the old product names do not match up to the new URL pattern

**Old URL Examples:**

`example.com/products.aspx?category=Foo&product=SuperLongNoBreakProductNameIDDescription`

`example.com/products.aspx?category=Foo&product=ProductNameDescription&var1=1293.123`

`example.com/products.aspx?category=Bar&product=ProductCategoryProdNameRandomNumbers`

(The old URL's are sometimes hitting 150+ characters.)

**New URL's:**

example.com/products/category/actual-product-name

There's no set, recognizable pattern to go from the old product name to the new one. There is for the category.

I've tried simple mod_alias Redirects, but understand that I need a RewriteRule instead. But I'm having problems. All I need is a 1-to-1 redirect for each of these 50 URL's. I thought I could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/products.aspx?category=Foo&product=ProductName
    /products/category/new-product-name/  [R=301,NC]
```

But that isn't working. I know this should be simple, but I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: For good form you should probably escape the period, e.g. `products\.aspx`.  Also, see answer below about RewriteCond.  Are there any other RewriteRules later in the .htaccess that could affect the rewritten URLs?  You might want to use the `L` flag where you're doing the external redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the response JMM. No other rewrite rules. The rest of the site Iw as able to take care of with simple redirects. No external redirects, either.

Comment: You don't clarify whether you have root config access and are doing these rewrites in your vhost config or alternatively using `.htaccess` based rules.  Because if the latter is true then maps don't work and your regexps are wrong: no leading / on per dir regexps.

Comment: @TerryE - sorry for being vague. This is being done in the vhost, not in .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pattern below for the rest of your redirect urls. Note that you escape special characters e.g. `?` ,  `.` and space  by adding a `\` in front of them

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /products\.aspx\?category=Foo&product=SuperLongNoBreakProductNameIDDescription [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /products/category/new-product-name/  [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: +1 for not using the obvious (and more complex) `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works, but there's one puzzling issue with the url. It show up as: `/products/category/new-product-name/?category=Foo&product=SuperLongN...` Not a dealbreaker, but puzzling. Also, I'm not using RewriteBase, as I have to put this in the vhost directly.

Comment: @the_zero add a `?` to the end to suppress the original query string i.e `RewriteRule ^ /products/category/new-product-name/? [R=301,NC]`

Comment: That did it. Sometimes I ask dumb questions I should already know the answer too! @ulrich-palha thank you so much for your help. One more question - if I have 50 of these will it cause any problems?

Comment: @the_zero It may be imperceptibly slower, but will not cause problems

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `RewriteMap` directive of [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

You can specify in a text file something like:

```
products.aspx?category=Foo&product=SuperLongNoBreakProductNameIDDescription /products/category/new-product-name
```

And in your `httpd.conf`

```
RewriteMap productmap /path/to/map/file.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${productmap:$1} [R=301,NC]
```

Tip: If it's a permanent redirect you want, make sure you set an appropriate `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header to instruct browsers to cache the 301.

Comment: Combine this with Ulrich's solution, because the path doesn't contain the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=Foo&product=ProductName$

RewriteRule ^products\.aspx$ /products/category/new-product-name/? [R=301,L]
```

Notes:

1. In per-dir (.htaccess) context, the per-dir prefix is stripped, so you can't start the `RewriteRule` pattern with `^/`.
2. You have to use `RewriteCond` to match against the query string.
3. As stated in another answer, a `RewriteMap` solution might be suited to this situation, if you have access to httpd.conf / the vhost definition for this site.  I'm not sure how that works with query strings though.
4. For something like this, it might be a better solution to rewrite all of these URLs to a server side script, and use the script to do the HTTP redirect for each URL.