# redirect dynamic URL to another URL in IBM websphere

Tags: websphere, url-routing, redirect

We are deploying a new document management system. The old system will will have all documents migrated to the new system. The new system will have a new URL and parameters to reach documents.

Over the last 10 years many documents, emails, portal sites, etc in our organization make reference to the old URLs. When we migrate to the new system, the old system will be decommissioned and all the URLs referring to the old system will be broken. However since the document id will be ported over to the new system this is opportunity to do a simple enough re-direct.

New system will be running on IBM Websphere.

Need to redirect:
`Http://olddms/document/dms_id?12345`
to
`http://newdmes/documentsabc/olddms_id?12345`

There would need to be a single page website that runs a script that parses out 12345 and dynamically adds it to the final destination URL and adds the 12345 at the end of it.

thus:

`Http://olddms/document/dms_id?12345`
goes to
`http://newdmsredirector/redirect (performs actual redirect)`
sends to
`http://newdms/documentsabc/olddms_id?12345`

I am not yet familiar with websphere and so can not even speculate on the scripting language for the middle wepage page (i.e: newdmsredirector)

I don't yet know the exact URLs but the general code to perform this is most important with tweaks to the script depending on the URL.

Also as a side note the newdmsredirector site or page would exist on the new websphere server and just redirect over to the other site.It could even be a page on the same DMS websphere site although I believe this part is irrelevant to solving the redirect code question.

Comment: Do you have a web server in front of WebSphere?

Answer (score 2):

If you have IBM HTTP Server (IHS) deployed in front of WebSphere Application Server, you can add [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) directives to `httpd.conf` web server config file.  I believe IHS is made available with WAS, at least the ND version.

An example of redirecting requests to "legacy" URLs is discussed in a [good post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975621/simple-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-for-messy-legacy-urls).

Comment: Definitely use mod_rewrite, or something like it, if you have a web server or proxy in front of WAS. Which you should have.